# How to create the custom module in the ansible

Tags: module, ansible

This is the custom module I have written to get the datetime from the current system. I have put the module in the /usr/share/my_modules folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import json

date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print(json.dumps({
    "time" : date
}))
def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = dict(
            state     = dict(default='present', choices=['present', 'absent']),
            name      = dict(required=True),
            enabled   = dict(required=True, type='bool'),
            something = dict(aliases=['whatever'])
        )
    )
module.exit_json(changed=True, something_else=12345)
module.fail_json(msg="Something fatal happened")
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And now When I try to execute it using command **ansible local -m timetest**
I Am getting this error

```
127.0.0.1 | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "The module timetest was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing. If this is a checkout, run 'git submodule update --init --recursive' to correct this problem."
}
```

why it is not executing my custom module ? please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `library` directory inside the directory where your playbook exist, your file structure will look like this:

```
.
|-- playbook.yml
|-- library
    `-- your-custom-module.py
```

Hope that might help you

Comment: Thanks Arbab. Should i mention this path in ansible.cfg ?

Comment: After putting the module in the library also , am not able to resolve the error.

Comment: ok now am able to execute the custom created module placed the in library folder inside the playbook and also through adhoc commands. Thanks so much Arbab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following Ansible test module instructions at http://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/developing_modules.html#testing-modules?

```
git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
source ansible/hacking/env-setup
chmod +x ansible/hacking/test-module
ansible/hacking/test-module -m ./timetest.py
```

Comment: ya i tried that imma. in that m able to get the output , but when i try to use the module through adhoc command , m getting the error

Comment: Thanks imma. Its working now. But i dont understand what this test-module does ?  i can test my custom module , when i try to use it in playbook or adhoc commands right ? Why this is specifically needed imma?

Comment: It is intended to help you test your module while developing, outside ansible. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/hacking/README.md. Once you build your module, in order to use it within Ansible you need to make sure it is in your ANSIBLE_LIBRARY variable.